# I cant view listbox in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, ide

I added tabPage component in my windows form in Visual Studio 2010. All worked very good, when today noticed that some components (listbox, 3 labels), although they are present in the project, I can not see them.

this is screenshot:
[image]

Sorry my incompetence, but this problem is really frustrating for me. How Can I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

You probably put the TabPage component on top of the other components.  Try right-clicking on the tab page and selecting "Send to back" or selecting the hidden components, right-clicking and selecting "Bring to front"

Comment: done but not resolved. It would seems that listbox and label are disappeared from my control

Comment: If you select the tab page control and "cut" it (Ctrl-X), are the missing controls visible?  You can paste the tab page control back so you don't lose it.

Comment: done, I have removed tab page control, and components (listbox1 and 3 labels) are again hidden, check this image please [link](http://i49.tinypic.com/34ys9ac.jpg)

Comment: What are the "location" and "size" values in the Properties tab for the missing controls?  Have you set them to values that are off the form?

Comment: yes all is configured correctly. for listbox1, size are (x=184, y=184), location is 100;100

Comment: RESOLVED!!! I noticed that in Form1.designer.cs it was remove this line: this.Controls.Add(this.listBox1);. After that I add it, component was visible.

Answer (score 0):

RESOLVED!!! I noticed that in Form1.designer.cs it was remove this line: this.Controls.Add(this.listBox1);.

After that I add it, component was visible.

this is screenshot:

[image]